# Is static_cast from base to derived considered "safe" in THIS particular context?

Tags: c++, static-cast

In a tree of polymorphic hierarchy objects, only the `Root` type instance has `null` `_parent`. I am using this method to fetch the root object of a particular tree node:

```
inline Root * root() {
    Object * r = this;
    while (r->_parent) r = r->_parent;
    return static_cast<Root *>(r);
}
```

I've been reading that static casting from base to derived is generally not considered safe, but what about my particular scenario, where a `Root` type can be identified by the `null` `_parent`?

Comment: It isn't safe. But it doesn't matter, as long as it's correct. What is your understanding of what "safe" means?

Comment: `static_cast` is precisely for those situations where *you* know (but the compiler may not know) that the dynamic type is the one you're casting to. If you don't know but merely suspect, ensure that the types are polymorphic and use a `dynamic_cast`. Still, since you're asking about safety, using a *universal object type* like `Object` is a Java-ism. It introduces unsafety via the need to downcast everywhere. Maybe it's just the naming here though, maybe you meant e.g. `Node`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - Object is not universal, the naming similarity to Java's Object is coincidental, it is merely the bottom-most class of the polymorphic hierarchy. It is far from universal and only establishes a few abstract methods that require implementation in the derived classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe so long as your invariant holds.  However invariants enforced over wide portions of large code bases rarely stay held.

At the least, I would insert a `Assert(dynamic_cast<...>(...))` here, and at every location `parent` is modified, in an attempt to enforce the invariant in debug.

Another approach would be to expose `virtual Root* as_root()` which only returns non-`nullptr` in `Root`.  This is more expensive than (most) `static_cast`s, but places the cast logic in a central searchable spot.  It is rarely the case that such a `virtual` call is your program's bottleneck.

The more interesting thing is 'what do you do if you do not find a `Root`?  Return `nullptr` probably, which means handling it at all call sites, at least at the level of `Assert`ing in debug.  If call sites are presumed not to handle it, return a `Root&` instead, and have failure call terminate/exit (after `Assert`) in debug (or release if you check it there, after logging/notifying/etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you know that `r` is of type `Root`, then a static cast is completely safe. In fact, the only reason the compiler allows you to use `static_cast` in this context is because `Root` and `Object` are compatible. If you try it with two incompatible types, it yields a compiler error - a `reinterpret_cast` is needed in that case.